# The value of a stochastic game

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, game-theory

I understand why a stochastic game with discounted payoff has a value $v$ and optimal strategies over the set of stationary strategies. But why is $v$ also the game's value over the set of behavioral strategies? Assume a two player zero-sum game with a finite state set and a finite set of actions at each state for each of the two players.

Comment: I think it derives from a variation on Kuhn's theorem (cf. chapter 6.4 pp. 238-243 of "[Game Theory](http://www.amazon.com/Game-Theory-Michael-Maschler/dp/1107005485/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1426172807&sr=8-2&keywords=solan+games)" by Maschler, Solan and Zamir, Cambridge University Press, 2013)